# How many integer numbers less than $10^4$, with digits $\{1,2,3,4\}$ only and constraints

Tags: combinatorics, integers

How many integer numbers less than $10^4$, with digits  $\{1,2,3,4\}$ only and no couples of digits like $\{13, 31, 24, 42\}$?

I calculated all the integers made of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ digits and less than $10^4$.
Then I removed all the numbers like
$13abc$
$a13bc$
$ab13c$
$abc13$

and did the same for $31, 24$ and $42$.
I used the dispositions of $4$ elements, in $5$ different places, with max $5$ repetitions (and then $4, 3, 2$, no repetitions).

I got **420**, while the problem book says **160**.

May you give me some suggestions about my procedure?
Thank you.

Comment: I would have thought $13abc>10^4$

Comment: "*In 5 different places*"  What is the largest number which is less than $10^4$?  Well... $10^4$ has a $1$ followed by four zeroes... $10000$.  The next number smaller than that?  $9999$.  Are there five places in $9999$?

Comment: Be warned also... are you being careful about numbers like $1324$?  Did you remove it once?  Or twice?

Comment: I would have guessed $4\times 3 \times 3 \times 3=108$ but I may have misunderstood the question.  With a fifth digit, I would have multiplied by another $3$ to get $324$

Comment: It is now understood what is the issue of my procedure. Thanks, I should have calculated first the numbers "in 4 different places" and so on.